# Blazor WASM Debugging in IDE when using url in host file pointing to localhost not working

Tags: debugging, blazor-webassembly, rider

I am running my blazor app on localhost, I can browse to it via a url in my hosts file which is set to redirect to localhost.

When browsing to the app directly through the localhost url I can successfully debug from my IDE (Rider). However if I browse to the url in my hosts file none of my breakpoints in the IDE get hit.

Does anyone know if you can debug blazor wasm this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35035), which sounds very familiar to what you're encountering. Therefore I'd say you're doing nothing wrong, and it's probably a bug.